# NSDecimalNumber subtraction

Tags: cocoa, math, subtraction, nsdecimalnumber

I need to subtract 0.5 from number a and set the answer to number b. My code looks like it would work but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The error I get Is on the subtraction line, the error says `incompatible type for argument 1 of 'decimalNumberBySubtracting:'`.

Heres my header: (Note: I only showed the numbers because the header is large)

```
    NSDecimalNumber *a;
    NSDecimalNumber *b;
```

Heres the rest: (Assume this is in an IBAction)

```
    b = [a decimalNumberBySubtracting:0.5];
```

If anyone knows how to properly subtract any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parameter must be an NSDecimalNumber too.

```
NSDecimalNumber *half = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.5"];
b = [a decimalNumberBySubtracting:half];
```

In your example you're using a float. There are two reason that cannot work:

- Objective-C cannot distinguis a float and an object at runtime, meaning you cannot supply a float instead of an object.
- Most decimal numbers cannot be described exactly in a binary system, therefore you have to work exclusively with decimal *or* binary numbers, but not both.